# after upgrade to ubuntu 12.10 unable to load GUI

Tags: upgrade

After the upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04, no GUI is displayed. I have to operate my PC in the Command line. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an ATI card? Maybe a HD4xxx or lower? And you used to have the proprietary drivers (fglrx). Well, this setup won't work anymore ([bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1068739)).

Unfortunatly, amd considers these cards legacy and they don't receive as much love as they deserve anymore. Remove the proprietary drivers (`sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`) and reboot to use the opensource drivers.

Comment: I did it and now the gnome desktop is displayed. But the GUI is not properly displayed. The start up screen some times appears and some times not displayed. The themes are not properly displayed. There is no blur effect in the dash and problem in the font color. And the most important there is problem of over heating and my pc is slow. These did not occur in the Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can you try to (re)-install the opensource drivers? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

If that does not work, try:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

And when asked, select gdm.

Comment: I did it but still no display. I still have to use the Command Line.

Comment: Did you reboot after that?

Comment: Yes. I did reboot my PC.

Comment: maybe install a desktop envoirement too? like gnome or unity?!

Comment: The desktop environment is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

did you use proprietary graphic drivers before upgrading?
if so, there might have been some upgrade problem. try to reinstall them following the appropriate instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto

If not, try issuing the command

```
grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

this should show the errors and hopefully the cause of your problems. add that to your problem in order to better understand what's the issue.